# backbone.js as adding Cyrillic symbols in routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, cyrillic

My script is a simple search machine, where I handle queries, suggestions and results. While typing, the script rebuilds a list of suggestions on keyup events.

I've got three routes: `""`, `"search/:query"` and `"answerQuestion/:id/:step"`. When a suggestion is clicked, the script goes to the route `"search/:query"`. So this is the part of code:

```
AnswerMachine.Views.Suggestion = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'suggestion-item alert alert-info',
    events: {
        'click': 'setQuery',
    },
    setQuery: function() {      
        //Сохраняем навигацию
        Backbone.history.navigate("search/" + this.model.get('title'));
        return this;
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.attr('id', this.model.get('id') + '_suggestion');
        //Записываем текст внутрь
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('title'));
        //Возвращаем наш объект
        return this;
    }
});
```

But when I click on the suggestion, for example: *Что тут происходит?*, it redirects me to the url: `/#search/'B>%20BCB%20?@>8AE>48B?`. So, what's the problem? Doesn't Backbone.js know cyrillic symbols?

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/DFeWR/ and http://fiddle.jshell.net/nikoshr/DFeWR/show/ An encoding problem when you save your file?

Comment: Nope, when I pressed here: [jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/DFeWR](http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/DFeWR) string 'Что тут происходит?' this string is logged: 'B> BCB ?@>8AE>48B?'

Comment: Maybe this is because I'm using Safari?

Comment: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2566, https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2666

Comment: Thanks, I tried escape method, but when I tried encodeURI() function and decodeURI() it start works in all browsers!

Comment: @XenoneX Could you add that as an answer? That could help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried escape method, but when I tried encodeURI() function and decodeURI() it start works in all browsers!